# Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa for transit in London and Madrid?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, indian-citizens

I am Indian citizen and am flying from Lima to Mumbai. My flights have a stop over at Madrid and London.

What transit visas do I require?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you are travelling from and what your final destinations are. For UK, refer https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa. For Madrid, although not an official site, check the information at https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/who-needs-schengen-visa/.